# almacenar string en un array

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++98

Quiero almacenar los nombres de los jugadores en una base de datos para que si ingresan el nombre de un jugador que ya estaba se vea la puntuacion de este, pero no me deja meter los jugadores en el arreglo alguien me podria ayudar por favor y gracias, es codigo hecho en c++

```cpp
#include "Cloud.h"
Cloud::Cloud()
{
    Player* p1 = new Player();
    Player* p2 = new Player();
}

void Cloud::cloud(std::string m[100])
{
    std::string almacen = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++) {
        almacen += m[i];
        if (m[p1] | m[p2]) {
        }
    }
}
```

Eso es lo que llevo.

Comment: No entendí. En qué arreglo quieres poner los jugadores?.

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos errores en tu sistema, te recomendaria utilizar un mapa o un vector para poder guardar a tus jugadores, una opcion podria ser la siguiente:

```
Cloud ::Cloud (){
playerScores = std::map<std::string,int>();
}

Void Cloud::addPlayerScore(std::string playerName, int score){
playerScores[playerName] = Score;
}
```

Comment: No hace falta llamar al constructor por defecto. Con declarar la variable en la clase es suficiente `std::map<std::string,int> playerScores;`